# Associate a folder to a record

Tags: apex, libraries, folder

In my work, I have been told to develop a VF page that would let the user to select a file and save it in existing/new folder in a library. There will be an option to create a new folder, there will be a list of folders where the user can select and choose the upload so that it will be saved in the folder.

Now the problem is that each of these folder needs to be associated with a  record in custom object P__c. I can create a new custom object and  store the folder P__C association, but is there an alternative available for this?

Comment: Why dont you use Salesforce content folder, rather than doing it in a custom way?
The feature was released at Summer 15.
Check the links below:
Idea : https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000007srnAAA
Release Note : http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_api_objects_new.htm?edition=&impact=

Comment: Hi. I am planning to use the salesforce content folder only. I have another object P__c, lets assume this object has 2 records, record1 and record2. It is like I have to make the record1 having folder1 and folder2, record2 has folder3 and folder4.. It would have been more convenient if the folder object had another field relatedentity or something.. I would have used that field to refer the P__c record.

Comment: I somewhere read that some object related to content management has a similar field for associating a record. I could not find that out now. Even if I find out, that might not be useful for me since it is not a contentfolder object, what does the salesforce developers do in these kind of situations is my question? Add a custom field? Is it doable? Is it worth doing?

Comment: Let's say you have folder system such as below :
Folder1 
   - Folder1_1
   - Folder1_2
Folder2
   - Folder2_1
        - Folder2_1_1
   - Folder2_2
And regarding to this structure, you want to associate the records with the folders also, am i right?

Comment: Hi, yeah, you are right. my question is all about how I could associate the folder1 to record1 in P__c object without creating another custom object.